# How do I get a custom validator working with formgroup?

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular2-formbuilder

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my custom Angular 5 formbuilder validator to work.

I want to use a `http.get` to get an array of interface `Record[]` which I will use to validate the ID in the form input.

My `get` call works on the server side (it returns only the `Record[]` objects with an id that matches the input. So, if the array is empty, the ID is unique, and the input is valid.

Any help (especially with code snippets!) would be really appreciated.

Here is sort of the basic scaffolding:

```
this.editContractorForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: ['', [Validators.required], this.checkId],
  configuration: this.formBuilder.array([])
});

checkId(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    this.http.get<Record[]>(url)...
    ...
    return ... ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you want to make an http call every time the validation fires? Especially with synchronous validation?

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-custom-async-validator-example

Comment: As R. Richards said, validation is executed on each character the user types. So if the Id is `deborahk` it will call checkId on `d`. Then again on `de`, then again on `deb`, etc. as the user types. You can want to instead handle the validation explicitly (not through a validator) after the user leaves the field.

Comment: @DeborahK I am using mat-error from Angular Material 2 to display the errors so I need to use a validator (unless I make a custom error  handler). Also, the ID is only 3-4 characters so I'm not worried about making http calls.

Comment: At least consider debouncing them then ...